# How to call from XML

Tags: php, xml

I have this following XML call from an API...

```
<response xmlns="http:/xml-api">
  <result id="123123" status="Success">
    <product>
      <identifiers>
        <store>
          <keycode>abcdefghi123</keycode>
          <title>Sweet Dreams Are Made out of these</title>
        </store>
         <location>
          <origin>South Africia</origin>
          <current>Brazil</current>
        </location>
      </identifiers>
    </product>
  </result>
</response>
```

I'm just trying to understand how to recall the `keycode` and the `title` values... Using my `simplexml_load()`...

I currently have set API call to `$myXMLdata`:

```
$xmlFile = simplexml_load_string($myXMLData) or die("Error!!!");
echo $xmlFile->response->result->product->identifiers->store[1];
```

But it doesn't seem to return anything from the XML page.

Comment: How are you calling the XML? Is it a file or what's `$myXMLData`?

Comment: `$myXMLData = ((the api call response))`
which is the XML tree above..

Answer (score 0):

You set not correct path to needed tags. Write it so:

```
echo $xmlFile->result->product->identifiers->store->keycode;
echo $xmlFile->result->product->identifiers->store->title;
```

Pay attention that root tag (response in the case) should be not included in the path

[demo](https://eval.in/583024)

Comment: hey thanks for the reply..

I still wasn't able to call back the value?? :( am i doing something wrong..??? is the api call not in a xml format?

Comment: have you seen the  demolink?

Comment: Did take a look...but I feel like my XML call from the API isn't ocrrect? is there anyway I can tell?

Comment: Why do you think that is's incorrect? looks like good XML. There is no problem while parsing it

Comment: Can you parse an API call on the same page and echo the same result?? cause thats what im doing..the XML is a result of that API call..

Comment: Do you think that I wii receive anothe result than in $myXMLData ?

Comment: No I don't think so... But I've updated the XML call; it seems there are more than 1 child node.. under idetnfiers...would that change the way the echo works?

Comment: show new xml in the question or put in eval and write ноу link

Comment: https://eval.in/583028 ...Heres the new XML?

Just want to say thanks for helping :D

Comment: --nvm figured it out.